# Error al ejecutar consulta en php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Buenas, estoy intentando separar una consulta de una pagina web en diferentes páginas pero a la hora de realizar la consulta me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''0','20'' at line 1 in
>   C:\wamp\www\php\tfg\web\principal\catalogo.php:58 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\php\tfg\web\principal\catalogo.php(58):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\wamp\www\php\tfg\web\principal\catalogo.php on line 58

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
if (isset($_GET['categoria']) OR isset($_POST['categoria'])){
        if (isset($_GET["pagina"]) OR isset($_POST['pagina'])) { $pagina  = $_REQUEST["pagina"]; } else { $pagina=1; };
        $resultadoPorPagina=20;
        $empezar=($pagina-1) * $resultadoPorPagina;
        $cat=$_REQUEST['categoria'];
        $conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=$con;dbname=$bdname",$superUser,$passdb);
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $consulta=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos where product_cat=:product_cat order by produc_id desc LIMIT :empezar,:resultadoPorPagina");
        $consulta->bindParam(":product_cat", $cat);
        $consulta->bindParam(":empezar", $empezar);
        $consulta->bindParam(":resultadoPorPagina", $resultadoPorPagina);
        $consulta->execute();
        $resultado=$consulta->fetchAll();
            foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                $contador=0;
        ?> 
            <div class="cuerpo col-4 col-m-4">
                <img class='imgTabla' src="<?php echo $fila['produc_imgPrinc'];?>"/><br/>
                <a href="producto.php?idProducto=<?php echo $fila['produc_id'];?>"><?php $fila["produc_nombre"];?></a><br/>
                <div class="precio"><?php echo $fila['produc_precio'];?></div>         <form method="post" action="catalogo.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="idProduct" value="<?php echo $fila['produc_id'];?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="pagina" value="<?php echo $pagina;?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="categoria" value="<?php echo $cat;?>"/>
                <input type="button" name="addCarrito" value="Añadir al carro"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php
        $contador++;
        if ($contador=3){
            echo "<br/>";
            $contador=1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: el limit solo lleva un parametro, por que lo pones como LIMIT empezar, :resultadoPagina?

Comment: Al añadir el segundo parámetro después de :empezar sirve para indicarle cuantas filas quiero que me muestre (en este caso 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está tomando `:empezar` y `:resultadoPorPagina` como String y no como int, prueba sustituyendo:

```
$consulta->bindParam(":empezar", $empezar);
$consulta->bindParam(":resultadoPorPagina", $resultadoPorPagina);
```

Por estas líneas:

```
$consulta->bindValue(':empezar', (int) $empezar, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$consulta->bindValue(':resultadoPorPagina', (int) $resultadoPorPagina, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Ese era el problema muchisimas gracias

Comment: @emilio789 Me alegro de que te haya funcionado, recuerda que puedes marcar la pregunta como solucionada.